# Handling large digit number variables in object-oriented C++

Tags: c++, digits, largenumber

I am working on numerical analysis using a solver (the programming is based on object-oriented C++) compiled with double precision, and my unit is 64-bits. My problem is that when the solver computes a large number - say -1.45 to the power 21, to take an actual example - and stacks it in the allocated memory by passing this value to an existing variable, it is converted to 0. So of course, when I later use this variable in a division I get a segmentation fault. I do not understand how this process works, and because I use the DP, I do not see how to fix the issue. Could anyone give me a hand with this matter please ?

In case it helps: I just ran a test where I state a=-1.45e+21, and "print" the value which is returned correctly by the solver. But when I do not use the "e" exponent and enter the full value (with 19 zeros) I get 0 in return. So I guess the issue/limitation comes from the number of digits, any ideas ?? Thanks !

Edit: I post a summary of the steps I go through to compute one of the variables which poses an issue. The others being similarly defined.
First I initialise the field pointer lists:

```
PtrList<volScalarField> fInvFluids(fluidRegions.size());
```

Where the class of volScalarField is just an array of double. Then I populate the field pointer lists:

```
fInvFluids.set
    (
        i,
        new volScalarField
        (
            IOobject
            (
                "fInv",
                runTime.timeName(),
                fluidRegions[i],
                IOobject::NO_READ,
                IOobject::AUTO_WRITE
            ),
            fluidRegions[i],
            dimensionedScalar
            (
                "fInv",
                dimensionSet(3,1,-9,-1,0,0,0),
                scalar(0)
            )
        )
    );
```

After this, I set the field regions:

```
volScalarField& fInv = fInvFluids[i];
```

And finally I compute the value:

```
   //   Info<< " ** Calculating fInv            **\n";
    fInv = gT*pow(pow(T/Tlambda, 5.7)*(1 - pow(T/Tlambda, 5.7)), 3);
```

Where T is field variable and Tlambda a scalar value defined at run time.

Comment: Please post the code where you are taking the power and saving it in the stack.

Comment: Consider using [GMP library](https://gmplib.org/) for big numbers.

Comment: I edit my comment. I checked the libraries compiled with the software and GMP-5.1.2 is installed, so I guess the issue occurs elsewhere.

Comment: None of the code you have posted is relevant. If you have a problem with `pov(x,y)`, post the actual values of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Well I have a problem when I compute a variable of the form K = pow(A/B, scalar(1)/scalar(3)); with A and B being arrays of double, and whose actual values range, for A, from 1e5 to 1e12, and for B, from 1e-3 to 1e-10. Doest it help ?

Comment: The "full value" is an (overflowing) `int`, `-1.45e+21` is a `double`. You need a type that doesn't overflow; try `-1450000000000000000000LL`.

Comment: Which variable is getting to 0? fInv, T, Tlamba, gT, i? How do you declare and use them?

Comment: I tried with your suggestion molbdnilo but it still returns 0 when I print the value at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

A `double` variable probably can't hold 19 zeroes either. A (decimal) digit takes more than 3 bits, so 19 zeroes will take at least 57 bits. A `double` typically has a mantissa which is only 53 bits.

However, that doesn't sound like the problem you have. In C++ **code**, expressions have a type as well. `1` is not the same as `1.0`. The first is an `int` and the second a `double`. While you can convert an `int` to `double`, they're not the same. An `int` most likely can hold values up to 2 billion , but formally it may have a limit as low as 32767. The solution to your problem might be as simple as adding a *twentieth* zero : `100000000000000000000.0` making it a `double`.

Comment: I finally found out that the error was coming from raising a negative base to the power exponent, using pow(). If the base is finite negative and the exponent is finite but not an integer value, it causes a domain error. I sorted out some work around using a sign function. However your solution was helpful as it did solve another mistake I had in the code when inputting large integer values. So thank you !

Comment: @SimoMJ That's to be expected. `pow(-1, 0,.5)` should be `0+1i` but `pow` doesn't retrun complex numbers.

Comment: Yes true also. One of my boundary conditions was not set properly and forcing values to diverge at some point, which made the power base go negative, I now solved this issue, but thanks a lot everyone for your suggestions.